# Python Subprocess.Popen attribute error?

Tags: python, awk

am new to python. sorry if the below question is very basic.

i am getting attribute error in the below case. kindly advice want i missed. 
am using python 2.4.

```
count = subprocess.Popen(["awk -F'n=' '{x+=$2}END{print x}' output"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE.communicate()[0],shell=True)
```

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'communicate'

thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: Please post the entire program, as short as possible. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Please post the entire error message, including the traceback. The line number in the traceback should correspond to the lines in the program you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
stdout=subprocess.PIPE.communicate()[0]
```

with

```
stdout=subprocess.PIPE
```

I guess this is what you wanted to type:

```
count = int(subprocess.Popen(["awk -F'n=' '{x+=$2}END{print x}' output"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0])
```

Please note that `shell=True` is insecure most of the time, and it's also unnecessarily slow. There is an easy way to avoid it in your case:

```
count = int(subprocess.Popen(('awk', '-Fn=', '{x+=$2}END{print x}', 'output'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])
```

Comment: To debug the *invalid literal* error, replace `int` with `repr`, and then `print(count)` to see what *awk* actually prints.